# How to get tkinter window to be already transparent when opening?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want a black window to fade in. When in fullscreen, it perfectly works but I need a specific size and there when its opened, it first appears black before it becomes transparent and the fading starts. Do you have any ideas how to achieve the same smooth effect as for the fullscreen version?

```
import tkinter as tk
 
class Fader(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.attributes("-alpha",0.0)
        #self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
        self.parent.geometry("600x800")
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.fade_in()       
 
    def fade_in(self):
        alpha = self.parent.attributes("-alpha")
        if alpha < 1:
            alpha += .01
            self.parent.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
            self.after(100, self.fade_in)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.bind("<Escape>",lambda e: root.destroy())
    Fader(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  May be you can add `self.parent.withdraw()` before setting the `alpha=0.0` and add `self.parent.deiconify()` before `self.fade_in()`.

Comment: Thaks for your help! Unfortunatly as soon as ```self.parent.deiconify() ``` is called, the same effect occures: opens in black fist, then fades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `withdraw()` to hide the window and `deiconify()` to show to window later on and increase the alpha. But it seems to not work unless you update the tasks or wait for the window to be visible.

**Method 1:**
Was able to fix this by using `update_idletasks()`, like:

```
class Fader(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.attributes('-alpha',0.0)
        self.parent.withdraw() #hiding the window
        #self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
        self.parent.update_idletasks() 
        self.parent.geometry("600x800")
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.fade_in()
 
    def fade_in(self):
        self.parent.deiconify() #bringing it back
        ..... #same code
```

**Method 2:**
Or like said by acw1668, you can use `wait_visibility()`, like:

```
class Fader(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.wait_visibility(self.parent)
        self.parent.attributes('-alpha',0.0)
        self.parent.withdraw()
        # self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
        self.parent.geometry("600x800")
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.fade_in()
 
    def fade_in(self):
        self.parent.deiconify()
        ...... #same code
```

A bit more about `wait_visibility()`:

> wait_visibility(window=None)
> Wait for the given widget to become visible. This is typically used to wait until a new toplevel window appears on the screen. Like wait_variable, this method enters a local event loop, so other parts of the application will still work as usual.

A bit more about `update_idletasks()`:

> update_idletasks()
> Calls all pending idle tasks, without processing any other events. This can be used to carry out geometry management and redraw widgets if necessary, without calling any callbacks.

Source :- https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm